# Add a position offset to x axes titles in R's ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

In R. I currently have this `ggplot`:

[image]

And I am looking to get the titles right in the center of the square, like this:

[image]

I took a look at `?element_text` but there is no position/offset setting. How can I move offset x-axes in a `ggplot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try with the `theme()` I have added:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]